# Relocation error when installing Image Magick

Tags: php, imagick

I am trying to install Image Magick on Fedora machine. I have successfully installed imagick before using yum without any problems encountered. But on this particular server, yum did not successfully install image magick because 'PHP and Apache were not installed with Yum' in the first place. This was the reply I got from the admin who installed Fedora on this machine.

When I was installing using yum, this was the error I got when I typed pecl install imagick:

php: relocation error: php: symbol SSLeay_version, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in file libcrypto.so.10 with link time reference

The instruction from this (http://jhalog.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/install-imagemagick-in-fedora-with-yum/) link usually works for me but not this time.

Then I tried to install imagick from source, I did not get any error but still PHP is unable to recognize it. I tried to run 'make test' and again the error above displayed.

Running 'php -m | grep imagick' also displays the above error message.

I don't have any advanced knowledge in Linux so I will appreciate any help.

Comment: If you want to install it with yum, you must delete all what installed without it and reinstall it with yum.

Comment: This is a live server with high traffic. I'd rather wait for someone to provide possible solution to the above problem.

Comment: Please show me commands you execute to compile it and output with errors

Comment: I just followed the instructions here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php. The error I am getting is the 'relocation error' above when I do 'make test'.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting what you problem really is, but this may help you. you dont have to download source file, extract, configure, make , make install, make test, install magick wand etc etc. Just follow the commands below,

First of all remove everything you have tried to make it work. Uninstall ImageMagick with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove imagemagick
```

Remove ImageMagick and all its dependencies with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove auto-remove imagemagick
```

Purge the config file of ImageMagick with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge imagemagick
```

Or similarly, like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge auto-remove imagemagick
```

Well, all your previous installation files are just gone. Now Install it purely and perfectly without any conflict or file modification. Enter the following two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

That was way too easy a thanks interwebs! Remember to restart/reload your webserver..

```
sudo service apache2 graceful
```

That's all. Check your php.ini or test with any simple script. For simple scripts to test ImageMagick you can refer to this [post](http://www.knowdipak.com/display-unsupported-image-formats-browser/).